# mysql - existing database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm building a site on Wordpress and, after a computer shutdown, when I attempt to log back in I'm getting a database error -

[image: Error report]

This is the abridged version - the actual error message carries on and covers all the tables in the database. The database is definitely there in phpmyadmin. When I look at any of the tables they have these error messages in them, this is the wp_users table -

[image: DB table errors]

I've done some background on this and seen that this has come up a few times, I'm not sure if I should simply reinstall wordpress and start again - this would not be a massive issue as I had only just started on the site so I hadn't actually entered anything on the database. However, what if this happens again and I'm quite far down the track - I need to understand how/why this has happened so I can deal with it if it does. Apparently it should involve deleting tables from the database but how do you do that manually (not on command line) ? Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Start over; and make regular database backups, so that you have a recent version to go back to if this should happen again.

Comment: @CBroe Where do I do the backup, in phpmyadmin?

Comment: That’s one way to do it, yes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've killed the mysql db process. You should stoping the process. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-startstop-excerpt/5.7/en/

MySql is holding some data in the memory of your computer. If you kill the process, these data will not been written in the file system.

Comment: But if I've done that, then I've done it without knowing I've done it so my concern is how do I avoid this in the future?

Comment: 1.) backups 

2.) check mysql config

3.) check that no other wordpress or other apps are using this database

4.) backups, backups, backups

Comment: This all suggests using the command line, though, which I'm not doing as its a wordpress site.

Comment: using command line is allready a good idea to work with mysql.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, I tried dropping the individual tables in the database but that still didn't work. In the end I dropped the entire database, re-installed wordpress and have started again afresh. Luckily I hadn't gotten very far with the site build so it wasn't a major disaster but I think the key here is to keep backing up as said above.
I'm still not sure what will happen if this happens again and I'm much further down the track but let's hope this was just a glitch...